# How to get current sender email ID in exchange using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have created a basic form in vb.net with one button. When we click on button an email will trigger to particular email ID mentioned in the code. And I want to include the current sender in email Cc while sending an email. I want to get the current sender email address. I'm using below code but it isn't working. Can anyone advise here.

```
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application()
Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem =  DirectCast(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)
Dim SenderEMailID = oMsg.SenderEmailAddress
```

Comment: First you have to explain what _"doesn't work"_ means, because there is an infinite amount of ways that your code can _not_ work in.

Comment: Hi Vincent, Sorry in case if my question wasn't clear. "Doesn't work" meant, It is giving me the sender email address.

Comment: But according to your question that is what you want? _"And I want to include the **current sender** in email Cc while sending an email. I struggling to get the **sender email address**"_

Comment: I have tried this and it works.

oApp.Session.CurrentUser.Address

Answer (score 0):

To get the current sender email address, use the below. It worked for me.

```
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application()
Dim SenderEmailID
SenderEmailID = oApp.Session.CurrentUser.Address
Messagebox.show(SenderEmailID)
```